# Dropping value of one variable when another changes

Tags: manipulate

## Context:

There is a list of lists `list` where lists are different length. Using one control I change a part of list to view, and with another one — what certain part of part to show at the end. Thought, `Length` could define here number of values in chosen part of `list`.

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}}; (* for example *)
Manipulate[list[[j, k]], {j, 1, 2, 1}, {k, 1, Length[list[[j]]], 1}]
```

## Problem:

When control of j-*th* part switches to part of `list` with k-*values* > then it was before, it leads to a mistake, though when switching in opposite direction slider disposes itself correctly:

[image: Mistake in an action]

## Question:

Do I desire that from `Length` in vain, and what is the solution of this problem? Assume, I can somehow set a value of k to 1, when j changes. How can I achieve this?

Thanks. I apologize for that the title not corresponding to an issue fully. Had no idea how to name it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can reset `k` whenever `j` changes if you customize the controller for it a little.  Use the second argument to `Dynamic` to set `k` to `1` (or anything else, for that matter):

```
list = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}}; (*for example*)
Manipulate[
 list[[j, k]],
 {j, 1, 2, 1, Manipulator[Dynamic[j, (k = 1; j = #) &], ##2] &},
 {k, 1, Length[list[[j]]], 1}]
```

---

*Edit*

An alternative is to completely specify the control:

```
{j, 1, 2, 1, Manipulator[Dynamic[j, (k = 1; j = #) &], {1, 2, 1}] &}
```

or

```
{{j, 1}, Manipulator[Dynamic[j, (k = 1; j = #) &], {1, 2, 1}] &}
```

The difference is minimal (it affects `Autorun`).  The first is exactly equivalent to original answer, except that to alter the domain `1, 2, 1`, there are two places to edit.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer fits great. I vaguely understand meaning of `#` in `Dynamic[j, (k = 1; j = #) &]`, but can't get sense of `##2` then. As I haven't completely grasped pure functions, can you explain that, please?

Comment: `#` stands for the first argument (in the `Function` in `Dynamic`) and `##2` stands for arguments 2 and above (in the `Function` `Manipulator[..] &`).  See [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616) for links to the funny symbols, and all the tutorials at the bottom of the [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) page for the rest, esp. [this part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedManipulateFunctionality.html#651832353)

Comment: @mikeonly  I added a couple of alternatives.  The first shows what `##2` becomes in this case, namely the single argument `{1, 2, 1}`.

Answer (score 2):

In this specific case, I prefer to keep both sliders' positions but instead of using directly their values, we can check if they do make sense and use a "reasonable guess" when they don't.

So, if `k>Length[list[[j]]]` instead of changing `k` into `1`, we can use `Length[list[[j]]]`.
I like the collateral effect of not losing the value of `k` in case we change `j` back into a value compatible with it. And I prefer to choose the last element when the index is greater than the length of the list than to choose the first.

This way, my 2 cents guess into your problem would be the following:

```
list = {{3, 5, 1, 7}, {8, 6}, {0}, {2, 9, 4}};
Manipulate[
  Style[list[[j, Min[k, Length[list[[j]]]]]], 
      If[k > Length[list[[j]]], Red, "Output"]],
  {j, 1, Length[list], 1},
  {k, 1, Max[Length /@ list], 1}
]
```

As I am not using directly the `k` value chosen by the user, I prefer to change the color but this is only an idea.

Comment: So..! I found more one Brazilian guy using MMA. Nice!

Comment: @Murta Don't worry, [you're not alone](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematica/query/120761/search-by-country?country=Brazil)... :)